# rotate transform not working correctly in FF and not working at all in IE

Tags: css, firefox, transform, mozilla, flip

I am trying to get images to rotate and either display another image behind or some text.

I have it working fine on Chrome but when I try it on Firefox, the rotate works but the same image displays at the back as at the front.

IE does just not work at all but from the googling I have done it appears that IE does not support the preserve-3d but I cannot find a satisfactory answer for FF.

The weird thing is that the rotate with the text behind the image works fine on FF, just not images.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="f1_container">
            <div class="f1_card" class="shadow">
            <div class="front face">
            <img src="images/beesm.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="back center">
            <img src="images/flysm.jpg"/>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and heres my CSS :

```
.f1_container {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 600px;
height: 397px;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

}
.f1_container {
perspective: 1000;
}
.f1_card {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: all 1.0s linear;

}
.f1_container:hover .f1_card {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
display: block;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
text-align: left;
background-color: #cac8c8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this site which will automatically add in all vendor prefixes once you paste in your css code. http://pleeease.io/play/ ensuring your code is all browser compatible.